# Getting non-contiguous text with lxml / ElementTree

Tags: python, html-parsing, lxml, elementtree

Suppose I have this sort of HTML from which I need to select "text2" using lxml / ElementTree:

```
<div>text1<span>childtext1</span>text2<span>childtext2</span>text3</div>
```

If I already have the div element as mydiv, then mydiv.text returns just "text1".

Using itertext() seems problematic or cumbersome at best since it walks the entire tree under the div.

Is there any simple/elegant way to extract a non-first text chunk from an element?

Comment: This seems like a bug. Have you tried to use `findtext(path)`?

Comment: As my answer apparently doesn't answer your question, could you explain further what you're looking for?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, lxml.etree provides full XPath support, which allows you to address the text items:

```
>>> import lxml.etree
>>> fragment = '<div>text1<span>childtext1</span>text2<span>childtext2</span>text3</div>'
>>> div = lxml.etree.fromstring(fragment)
>>> div.xpath('./text()')
['text1', 'text2', 'text3']
```

Comment: doc.xpath('/div/text()')[1:2] will give you non-first text from element

Comment: Well "a way to extract a non-first text chunk" includes many possibilities after you get all the text items as a list, such as `random.choice(div.xpath('./text()')[1:])` or `set(div.xpath('./text()')[1:]).pop()`.  However, since the OP knows enough to ask about lxml, I figure list manipulation is small beans.

Answer (score 6):

Such text will be in the `tail` attributes of the children of your element.  If your element were in `elem` then:

```
elem[0].tail
```

Would give you the tail text of the first child within the element, in your case the `"text2"` you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

As llasram said, any text not in the `text` attribute will be in the `tail` attributes of the child nodes.

As an example, here's the simplest way to extract *all* of the text chunks (first and otherwise) in a node:

```
html = '<div>text1<span>childtext1</span>text2<span>childtext2</span>text3</div>'

import lxml.html    # ...or lxml.etree as appropriate
div = lxml.html.fromstring(html)

texts = [div.text] + [child.tail for child in div]
# Result: texts == ['text1', 'text2', 'text3']
# ...and you are guaranteed that div[x].tail == texts[x+1]
# (which can be useful if you need to access or modify the DOM)
```

If you'd rather sacrifice that relation in order to prevent `texts` from potentially containing empty strings, you could use this instead:

```
texts = [div.text] + [child.tail for child in div if child.tail]
```

I haven't tested this with plain old stdlib ElementTree, but it should work with that too. (Something that only occurred to me once I saw Shane Holloway's lxml-specific solution) I just prefer LXML because it's got better support for HTML's ideosyncracies and I usually already have it installed for `lxml.html.clean`

Answer (score 1):

Use `node.text_content()` to get all of the text below a node as a single string.