# How to handle Element.tail in lxml/elementtree .iter()

Tags: python, lxml, elementtree

Thinking how the following tree iteration problem works has tied knots in my brain that maybe some of you can help resolve/untie.

I have (TEI) XML texts and want to segment them by `<milestone>`s. In order to label the segments, I want to use an attribute of the `<milestone>` *and* one of the parent `<div>` elements. I think this means that I cannot use the `itertext()` method because it does not allow me to access those attributes while handling the text nodes. So my approach is to use the `iter()` method, feed all text contents into a buffer and flush that into output segments (a dictionary of label and text content of the segment) when I run into a milestone element. When I am *not* at a milestone element in the iteration, I write `.text` of the present node into my buffer.

The difficult thing is when and how to handle `.tail` text: When I am just testing the current node for `.tail` and append it to the buffer, then it will appear before `.text` of the current node's children (while in effect it should come after) and if I don't test for it, I will never have another chance to catch it, or did I get this wrong?

Can I even use lxml's `iter()` at all or do have to build my own recursive iteration function? (I tried to segment the text via an XPath expression before, but the performance of that was inacceptable (>24h).

I apologize for the long and messy xml snippet, but I cannot figure out which passages I could tidy up or skip for this question. (And some of the other questions (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683997/getting-non-contiguous-text-with-lxml-elementtree)) are not applicable precisely because I have more messy xml.

Thanks for any help.

Code:

```py
from typing import Dict
import lxml
from lxml import etree

def segment(chapter: lxml.etree._Element) -> Dict[str, str]:
    segments = {} # this will be returned
    t = []        # this is a buffer
    chap_label = str(chapter.get("n"))
    sect_label = "0"
    for element in chapter.iter():
        if element.get("unit")=="number":
            # milestone: fill and close the previous segment:
            label = chap_label + "_" + sect_label
            segments[label] = " ".join(t)
            # reset buffer
            t = []
            # if there is text after the milestone,
            # add it as first content to the buffer
            if element.tail:
                t.append(" ".join(str.replace(element.tail, "\n", " ").strip().split()))
            # prepare for next labelmaking
            sect_label = str(element.get("n"))
        else:
            if element.text:
                t.append(" ".join(str.replace(element.text, "\n", " ").strip().split()))
            if element.tail:
                t.append(" ".join(str.replace(element.tail, "\n", " ").strip().split()))
    # all elements are processed,
    # add text remainder/current text buffer content
    label = chap_label + "_" + sect_label
    segments[label] = " ".join(t)
    return segments

nsmap = {"tei": "http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"}
xp_divs = etree.XPath("(//tei:body/tei:div)", namespaces = nsmap)

segmented = {}
divs = xp_divs(document)
segments = (segment(div) for div in divs)
for d in segments:
    print(d)
```

Input document (I left much text in it so it is easier to see where phrases end up in the output document):

```xml
document=etree.fromstring("""
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
<text>
  <body>
    <div n="1">
      <p>
      ... <milestone unit="number" n="9"/>aun que el amor de Dios ha de ser
      grandissimo ..., como despues de. S. Tho.
      <ref target="#nm-0406">b</ref><note xml:id="nm-0406"><p>1. Sec. quaestio
      109. ar. 3.</p></note>, poco ha lo tratamos
      <ref target="#nm-0407">c</ref><note xml:id="nm-0407"><p>in addit. ca.
      Quoniam. de consec. disti. 1. nu. 10.</p></note>. Anadimos, (virtual)
      <milestone unit="number" n="10"/>porque aquella basta, ...
      <ref target="#nm-0408">d</ref><note xml:id="nm-0408"><p>in 4. dis. 14.
      q. 1. art. 3.</p></note>, que pone exemplo ..., que Gabriel sigue
      <ref target="#nm-0409">e</ref><note xml:id="nm-0409"><p>in 4. dis. 14.
      q. 1. col. 12. &amp; 13. &amp; in. 3. di. 27. q. 1. co. 15.</p></note>.
      <milestone unit="other" rendition="#asterisk"/> Y aun, aquel doctissimo,
      ... <ref target="#nm-040a">f</ref><note xml:id="nm-040a"><p>In Codice de
      poeni. q. 2.</p></note>, y con razon, ..., el martyrio atribuya esto
      <ref target="#nm-040b">g</ref><note xml:id="nm-040b"><p>Lib. 2. c. 16.
      de natu. &amp; gra.</p></note>, porque mas haze para esto el amor, ...
      que lo que se padece <ref target="#nm-040c">h</ref><note xml:id="nm-040c">
      <p>Arg. c. 13. 1. ad Corinth.</p></note>. Y puede ser que mas ame, ...,
      como lo prueua bien Medina
      <ref target="#nm-040d">i</ref><note xml:id="nm-040d"><p>in predi.
      q. 2.</p></note>. Por lo qual largamente paresce quan lexos esta esto
      dela opinion de Luthero<milestone unit="other" rendition="#asterisk"/>.
      De lo dicho se collige la razon, ..., segun Syluestro
      <ref target="#nm-040e">k</ref><note xml:id="nm-040e"><p>verb. Contritio.
      q. 1.</p></note>. Diximos <milestone unit="number" n="11"/> (auer
      pecado,) porque el arrepentimiento ...
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</text>
</TEI>""")
```

Result (for readability, linewrapped and displayed here as csv):

```
1_9,"aun que el amor de Dios ha de ser grandissimo ..., como despues
     de. S. Tho. b , poco ha lo tratamos 1. Sec. quaestio 109. ar. 3.
     c . Anadimos, (virtual) in addit. ca. Quoniam. de consec. disti.
     1. nu. 10."
1_10,"porque aquella basta, ... d , que pone exemplo ..., que Gabriel
      sigue in 4. dis. 14. q. 1. art. 3. e . in 4. dis. 14. q. 1. col.
      12. & 13. & in. 3. di. 27. q. 1. co. 15. Y aun, aquel doctissimo,
      ... f, y con razon, ..., el martyrio atribuya esto In Codice de
      poeni. q. 2. g , porque mas haze para esto el amor, ... que lo que
      se padece Lib. 2. c. 16. de natu. & gra. h . Y puede ser que mas
      ame, ..., como lo prueua bien Medina Arg. c. 13. 1. ad Corinth.
      i . Por lo qual largamente paresce quan lexos esta esto dela
      opinion de Luthero in predi. q. 2. . De lo dicho se collige la
      razon, ..., segun Syluestro k . Diximos verb. Contritio. q. 1."
1_11,"(auer pecado,) porque el arrepentimiento ..."
```

(You can see, for example, that the content of the note `nm-0408` should come after "porque aquella basta, ... d ", but it does come only later, after "que Gabriel sigue"...)

Comment: I have made the code runnable and introduced a couple of functions like `str.replace("\n", " ")`, cleaning the resulting text, so that it is easier to read and compare original document and result. This makes the example non-minimal but I hope it is still a good idea.